# ANOVA with Some Repeated Trials - Independence Assumption

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, sas, independence, confounding

I have some cross sectional data in which I would like to perform a basic ANOVA on. Some of the measurements are repeats from the same subjects, but the "independent variable" is not necessarily the same for each subject every time. Thus, I am thinking to treat each trial as independent from each other, would this be accurate? Here are the specifics about the data:

I have 115 observations coming from a total of 87 subjects. Some subjects repeated the test (1 year later at the earliest), most did not. The independent variable here is a score (3 levels ranging from 0 to 2). If the subject repeated the test, their score can be different each time. The dependent variables of interest are some biomarkers, all continuous variables.

I checked all the baseline characteristics and the only significant one is GENDER between the independent score cohorts (as expected? since gender remains the same while the others, like age, weight, etc. change over time). Thus, as long as I adjust for this variable in each of my ANOVA models for all of the DVs of choice, will I be OK in terms of meeting the assumptions of the ANOVA? Would it make sense to adjust for ID?